# Onedrive API : upload file in a specific directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, xlsx, onedrive

I use python and Onedrive and I want to copy one of my onedrive file on a specific directory.

On Onedrive I have the following directories and files on my root space

```
1- /test/cdm
--> drive-api.py

2-  /test/cdm/data
--> tue.xlsx

3- /all-data
```

I want to copy **tue.xlsx** from **/test/cdm/data**  to **/all-data**

I use this code in drive-api.py

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/login/authorized'
client_id = 'xxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'yyyyyyyyy'
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)
# If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
# which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)
```

This code work fine but it's not the right directory

```
returned_item = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children['tue-copie.xlsx'].upload('data/tue.xlsx')
```

Question : 
How can I specify /all-data directory ?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, you just need to change `id` to `path` in the client.item()

So assuming the folder is called `all-data`, you can upload it like this:

```
returned_item = client.item(drive='me', path='all-data').children['sample.xlsx'].upload('sample.xlsx')
```